# How to write an Clojure macro to get var's value?

Tags: clojure

```
user=> (def v-1 "this is v1")
user=> (def v-2 "this is v2")
user=> (defmacro m [v] (symbol (str "v-" v)))
user=> (m 1)
"this is v1"
user=> (m 2)
"this is v2"
user=> (let [i 2] (m i))
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: v-i in this context, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:73:12)
```

Can I write a macro let both

`(m 2)`

and

`(let [i 2] (m i))`

get "this is v2" ?

Answer (score 9):

This is possible without a macro:

```
(defn m [v] (var-get (resolve (symbol (str "v-" v)))))

(m 1) ;; => "This is v1"
(let [i 2] (m i)) ;; => "This is v2"
```

You can use a macro too if you want:

```
(defmacro m [v] `@(resolve (symbol (str "v-" ~v))))
```

Comment: Thanks. more question, If I has:

(defmacro m [v] `(symbol (str "v-" ~v)))    

then:

(let [i 2] (m i))

can get a 'v-2 symbol, Is it possible to get the value?

Comment: Thanks again.
So, this requirement can't direct return var's value (without resolve and var-get so on) by macro, right?

Comment: @jamesqiu AFAIK you must resolve the var by name somehow, e.g. `resolve`, `intern`, `clojure.lang.Var/find`, etc., then get its value.

Comment: Note that `(defmacro m [v] `@(resolve (symbol (str "v-" ~v))))` simply expands to `@(resolve (symbol (str "v-" ~v)))`, i.e. the actual lookup happens at runtime, with the code performing the lookup inlined in the caller of the macro. This is equivalent to writing `@(resolve …)` by hand wherever this pattern is needed. The cleaner solution would use a function with the same body minus the syntax-quote + unquote.

Answer (score 1):

A plain function seems much more likely to be what you want.

First, though, to address the original question, if you wanted to insist on using a macro, macros are regular functions that happen to be called at compile time, so you can look up a Var using its symbolic name and obtain its value using `deref` just like you could at (your application's, as opposed to your macro's) runtime:

```
(defmacro var-value [vsym] @(resolve vsym))

(def foo 1)

(var-value foo)
;= 1
(macroexpand-1 '(var-value foo))
;= 1
```

Note that the above `1` is the actual macroexpansion here. This is different to

```
(defmacro var-value [vsym] `@(resolve ~vsym))
```

in that the latter expands to a call to `resolve`, and so the lookup given that implementation is postponed to your app's runtime.

```
(macroexpand-1 '(var-value foo))
;= (clojure.core/deref (clojure.core/resolve foo))
```

So this code will just be inlined wherever you call the macro.

Of course the macro could also expand to a symbol – e.g.

```
(defmacro prefixed-var [suffix]
  `(symbol (str "v-" ssuffix)))
```

will produce expansions like `v-1` (for `(prefixed-var 1)`) etc.

Going back to the subject of the suitability of macros here, however, if you use a macro, all the information that you need to produce your expansion must be available at compile time, and so in general you cannot use the values of `let` / `loop` locals or function arguments in your expansion for the fundamental reason that they don't have any fixed value at compile time.<sup>1</sup>

Thus the cleanest approach would probably be to wrap a `resolve` call in `defn` and call the resulting function – although of course to know for sure, we'd need to know what problem you were trying to solve by introducing a macro that performs a Var lookup.

---

<sup>1</sup> Except if statically assigned constant values, as in the example given in the question text; I'm assuming you're thinking of using runtime values of locals in general, not just those that whose initialization expressions are constant literals.